# How to use a Map that has the same entity as the value for multiple keys of a basic type

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm

I'm reading Pro JPA 2 and it gives the following example:

```
@Entity
public class Department {
    @Id private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="department")
    @MapKeyColumn(name="CUB_ID")
    private Map<String, Employee> employeesByCubicle;
    // ...
}
```

The book mentions that `CUB_ID` will be a column on the `Employee` entity table. But how would that  support (or could be changed to support) the same employee working in more than one cubicle, e.g. the map containing

```
{"cube A1": {"id":"1","name":"John Doe"},
 "cube A2": {"id":"1","name":"John Doe"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can do that by updating the relationship in Department side to `@ManytoMany`  and `@JoinTable` ( You can keep the `@ManyToOne` on the employee side or uni directional)

```
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable
    @MapKeyColumn(name="CUB_ID", nullable = true)
    private Map<String, Employee> employeesByCubicle;
```

- Output: As you can see, it is keeping the reference to same employee in both cubicles

```
        Employee employee = new Employee(1l, "Kav");
        Map<String, Employee> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("Cube1", employee);
        map.put("Cube2", employee);
        Department dep = new Department(1l, map);
        employee.setDepartment(dep);
        //Saved a department and an employee with 2 cubicles
        departmentRepository.save(dep);

        Department retrieved = departmentRepository.findById(employee.getId())
                                                    .get();
        System.out.println(retrieved);
        //Output
        //Department{id=1, employeesByCubicle={Cube1=Employee{id=1, name='Kav'},
        //                                     Cube2=Employee{id=1, name='Kav'}}}
```

- You can find the program that runs, inserts the data, fetches, prints and then shutdown. https://github.com/kavi-kanap/stack-overflow-62840098